# Query is not working in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query with works for e.g. in FlySpeed SQL Query app but not in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table1 t
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3) as dt
     FROM 
         table1
     GROUP BY 
         col1, col2, dt
     HAVING 
         COUNT(*) > 1) temp ON t.col1 = temp.col1                  
                            AND t.col2 = temp.col2 
                            AND CONVERT(date, t.col3) = dt
ORDER BY 
    t.col1 desc
```

I get this in SSMS:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'dt'.

Comment: try `temp.dt` like you do `temp.col1`

Comment: You can't use the column alias in the group by, so instead of  `GROUP BY col1, col2, dt` you need to use the entire expression - `GROUP BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)`. The reason for this is that the `GROUP BY` is evaluated before the `SELECT`, so when you evaluate this the query engine has no knowledge of the column `dt` (that being said, there are some engines that do allow this, but it doesn't conform to the SQL standard)

Comment: For what it is worth, you could achieve the same thing with a window function, and only read from the table once:      `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, cnt = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)) FROM table1) t WHERE t.Cnt > 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below query,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
JOIN (
          SELECT col1, 
                 col2, 
                 CONVERT(date, col3) as dt
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) temp
  ON t.col1 = temp.col1 
  AND t.col2 = temp.col2 
  AND CONVERT(date, t.col3) = dt
ORDER BY t.col1 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
JOIN (SELECT col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3) as dt
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
  ON t.col1 = temp.col1 AND t.col2= temp.col2 and CONVERT(date, t.col3)=temp.dt
ORDER By t.col1 desc
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I didnt see the GROUP BY, you can only order by an ALIAS but not GROUP BY. I updated the script

Answer (score 1):

Change GROUP BY clause from

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, dt
```

To:

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the column alias in the group by. It's better you use this expression instead:

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, CONVERT(date, col3)
```

in place of

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, dt
```

I think this will work.